# AWS Lambda Python - Get Physical Processor Information

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I know its counter intuitive, but... Is it possible to get physical CPU model information via python for AWS Lambda function? Or is it completely abstracted.

```
cat /proc/info output returns 
nmodel name\t: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Processor @ 2.50GHz
```

but no specific model information

Comment: It is all virtualized. Is there any particular reason why you need this information? There might be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks John, sure I would be interested in your thoughts for a workaround. It was more for curiosity to understand model to derive CPU TDP.

Comment: What is driving your desire to know the Thermal Design Power? Is this for an ecological calculation of energy usage? AWS publishes sustainability information.

Comment: Thanks John, understood. It was moreover to validate adherence to sustainability data.